# Mapping through Data does not Return CSS Correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm mapping through some redux data and would anticipate given the css the following elements would stack ontop of each other, with each result having their own unique container.

However it appears they're lumping into one div.

Am I incorrectly mapping this data?

https://gyazo.com/31c7b43a00da89d84fa18bf144f3dd2e?token=cf8ebf5cdba4e9a125619d8b8707fbc7

```
  const searchResults = useSelector(state => state.jobsearch.roles.map(role => role.title))
    
    const SearchResultsText = () => {
      return (
          <JobContainer title={searchResults}>
                    <Typography>
                            {searchResults} 
                    </Typography>
                </JobContainer>
      )
      ;
    };
```

And the jsx itself:

```
 {searchResults && searchResults.length < 3 && (
                    <SearchResultsText/>
                )}
```

And also the css for the container is:

```
const JobContainer = styled.div`
    
    background-color: red;
`;
```

As well at the parent container

```
const SearchContent = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color:blue;
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the searchResults with a JSX element.

```
<JobContainer>
  {searchResults && searchResults.length < 3 && searchResults.map((result) =>
    (<SearchResultsText text={result} />)
  )}
</JobContainer>
```

Also, create a property in SearchResultsText so you can pass each value to the component.

```
const SearchResultsText = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <Typography>
      {text}
    </Typography>
  );
};
```